# python: sort list of strings when it's a list of numbers

Tags: python, list, sorting

Newbie here with the python interpreter.

Why am I not able to sort this list of strings?

```
>>> list = ['296098', '12805', '10445635', '11679960']
>>> print list.sort()
None
>>> print list.sort(key=float)
None
```

Why isn't python able to sort this list of string for me?

Comment: `list.sort()` sorts the list in place – but it is a function, and it does not return the list. It's kinda of mentioned in [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) – always a good place to check, I must add.

Comment: BTW, you should not use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: The other place to check would be a Google search: "why does list.sort() return None"

Answer (score 5):

`list.sort()` mutates the list in place, instead of returning a new list.

```
>>> list = ['296098', '12805', '10445635', '11679960']
>>> list.sort()
>>> list
['10445635', '11679960', '12805', '296098']
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, `list.sort()` manipulate the list in place, which means when you call it, the list is already sorted, and the default return value is `None`

```
list = ['296098', '12805', '10445635', '11679960']
list.sort()
list
Out[4]: ['10445635', '11679960', '12805', '296098']
```

Secondly, above is sort by string value, you want to sort by the numerical value, you can use `key=int`. Remember you can replace int with any custom methods:

```
list.sort(key=int)
list
Out[6]: ['12805', '296098', '10445635', '11679960']
```

Last but not least, you should not use `list` as a variable name, as it's builtin function name already.

Answer (score 1):

`list.sort` sorts the `list` in place. Some Python programmers would prefer `sorted` which will return a sorted `list` and leave the initial `list` untouched

```
In [2]: l=['296098', '12805', '10445635', '11679960']

In [3]: sorted(l, key=float)
Out[3]: ['12805', '296098', '10445635', '11679960']

In [4]: l.sort(key=float)

In [5]: l
Out[5]: ['12805', '296098', '10445635', '11679960']
```